# How to calculate the duration between two datesin same column in SQL based on certain field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the Break Duration of user For e.g(Break Duration=Lock-UnLock Time) or
(Break Duration=Login-TaskPause)

Can anyone please tell me how to calculate that?

In the below example whenever there is a break in EventType calculate Previous row of Date-Next  row of date.How can i achieve that?

Below is my table

```
EventId  EventDate                EventType   Userid
1   2015-11-05 13:54:28.900   Login        10
2   2015-11-05 13:55:27.527   Lock         10
3   2015-11-05 13:55:27.537   Break        10
4   2015-11-05 13:55:37.037   Unlock       10
5   2015-11-05 14:33:26.347   Login        10
6   2015-11-05 14:33:46.243   Break        10
7   2015-11-05 14:34:34.570   TaskPause    10
```

Desired Output will be

```
Userid  Break_Duration(In sec)
10         10
10         68
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Comment: Desired Output will be Userid and Break Duration Column

Comment: @Rajashri does my answer help you? If it does, could you please put closure to your question by marking it accepted? Thank you.

Comment: @zedfoxus-i have multiple scenarios in Break event type and everytime i have to create different select statements and union which i think is not a good way.What i am looking is whenever there is a Break in event type subtract the previous event date-next event date.can we short this query?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a somewhat identical query but with MySQL since I don't have SQL Server access right this minute and SQLFiddle's SQL Server option is acting up. You can adapt this to SQL Server rather easily.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36d576/26

**Table**

```
create table test(
  eventid int, 
  eventdate datetime,
  eventtype varchar(20),
  userid int
);
insert into test values 
(1   ,'2015-11-05 13:54:28.900',   'Login',        10),
(2   ,'2015-11-05 13:55:27.527',   'Lock' ,       10),
(3   ,'2015-11-05 13:55:27.537',   'Break' ,       10),
(4   ,'2015-11-05 13:55:37.037',   'Unlock' ,      10),
(5   ,'2015-11-05 14:33:26.347',   'Login'   ,     10),
(6   ,'2015-11-05 14:33:46.243',   'Break'    ,    10),
(7   ,'2015-11-05 14:34:34.570',   'TaskPause' ,   10);
```

**Query**

```
select * from (
  -- get first Login record before unlock
  select t.userid, time_to_sec(timediff(u.eventdate, t.eventdate)) as sec
  from test t 
  inner join (
    -- get record for unlock
    select eventid, userid, eventdate from test
    where eventtype = 'Unlock' and userid = 10
  ) u on t.userid=u.userid
  where 
    t.eventtype = 'Lock' 
    and t.eventid < u.eventid
    and t.userid = 10
  order by t.eventid asc
  limit 1
) a

union all 

select * from (
  -- get lastest Login record before taskpause
  select t.userid, time_to_sec(timediff(u.eventdate, t.eventdate)) as sec
  from test t 
  inner join (
    -- get record for taskpause
    select eventid, userid, eventdate from test
    where eventtype = 'TaskPause' and userid = 10
  ) u on t.userid=u.userid
  where 
    t.eventtype = 'Login' 
    and t.eventid < u.eventid
    and t.userid = 10
  order by t.eventid desc
  limit 1
) b
```

**Result**

```
| userid | sec |
|--------|-----|
|     10 |   9 |
|     10 |  69 |
```

In SQL Server, you can use `datediff(second, time1, time2)` to get seconds between two times. Most other things can be optimized once you get the results you want.